# How can I toggle/cycle through settings?

Tags: source-engine

I want to be able to cycle through names, scripts
 or source commands.

By cycling i mean switching to another name, script or command after i press a button. Pressing this button repeatedly will go through all those entries until the end where it will reach the first entry again.

For example if I have 3 nicknames A, B and C and want to cycle through those.

Pressing a button shall execute a command that changes my name to B and after pressing the same button again my name will be changed to C. Pressing again will result in my name changing to A again, completing the cycle.

How would a template for this look like?

Comment: While I do like the sharing of information by answering your own question, this is a poor question when looked at on its own. It's pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: it was formated this way on arqade by high rep users so i just copied over since arqade do claim this is offtopic on their site. could you give me any advice what to improve? if you are not familiar with source engine scripts (and what users demand in it) it may not be clear to you at first but at the same time the question might not be interesting for you in the first place.

Comment: Provide some brief background on what exactly you are "cycling" in or what exactly you mean by "cycling" in this context. Even though the question is specific in its focus you should be able to write it in such a way as include enough basic background information to give somebody who doesn't know the details of the Source engine to understand what are asking. As written, this question is only vaguely clarified by *your answer*, which is bad.

Comment: @Wandang Thanks, that's a bit clearer. In the future, if you frame the question in the context of the problem you're trying to solve (instead of *just* "How to do X?"), along with how you want it to work it'll give people a good idea of what you want and why.

Comment: This should not have been migrated in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To cycle through different names/settings/scripts etc you need to follow the following pattern (At the end there is the full code if you want to skip the details):

## Cycling through self made scripts using alias

#### Step 1: Set a starting point

```
alias cycler "useName1"
```

Now if we trigger **cycler** -> **useName1** will be executed.

**cycler** and **useName1** are names i made up. You can change those to whatever fits your needs.

#### Step 2: Define useName1 and set cycler

```
alias useName1 "setinfo name "First_name"; alias cycler useName2"
```

This will execute the namechange (or your script or your setting) and set the cycler to **useName2**. The next time we trigger **cycler** -> **useName2** will be executed.

**useName2** is a name i made up too.

#### Step 3: Define useName2 and set cycler

```
alias useName2 "setinfo name "Second_name"; alias cycler useName1"
```

This will execute the second namechange (or your script or your setting) and set the cycler back to **useName1**. The next time we trigger **cycler** -> **useName1** will be executed again. The cycle is complete.

#### Step 4: Bind your cycler to a key

```
bind "key" cycler
```

We are done. You can repeat part 2 and 3 for other definitions (if you switch through 15 names, go for it). Just let the last set the cycler onto the first!

### Full Code Solution 1

```
alias cycler "useName1"
alias useName1 "setinfo name "First_name"; alias cycler useName2"
alias useName2 "setinfo name "Second_name"; alias cycler useName1"
bind "key" cycler
```

---

## Cycling through settings provided by the source engine

If you want to iterate through settings that are predefined by the `source engine` and require a number as a value, for example:

```
net_graph x (value 0 to 3 are possible)
sensitivity x (any value is possible)
```

then you don't need to use the cycler above.

Instead source provides us with two nifty commands:

### Toggle

`toggle command value1 value2 value3`

This command let's us cycle through the setting with specific values.

For example:

`toggle net_graph 1 2 3`

Starts with executing **net_graph 1**. Using this command again executes **net_graph 2** and so forth.

To use this command quickly just go ahead and bind it to a key

### Full Code toggle

`bind "x" "toggle net_graph 1 2 3"`

### Incrementvar

`incrementvar command min max steps`

This let's us cycle through the setting in defined steps.

For example:

`incrementvar net_graph 1 3 1`

Starts with **net_graph 1** and increases each step +1. This means executing the command again results in **net_graph 2**. The next would be **net_graph 3**.
After that it will jump back to **net_graph 1** because we told him that the max value would be 3.

The other example would be:

`incrementvar sensitivity 200 800 200`

which increases the sensitivity by 200 each time we execute this until it reaches 800 at which point it will drop to 200 again.

The steps can be negative to (cycle backwards) like:

`incrementvar sensitivity 200 800 -200`

To use this command we still need to bind it:

### Full Code incrementvar

`bind "key" "incrementvar sensitivity 200 800 200"`

## Another Solution

Another solution to cycle through variables (settings,commands etc) would be to rebind the button directly.

This however is discouraged since it takes more resources from the system while just changing an alias to another does not interfere with keymapping at all which is therefore quite static.

Still I will show it for completeness

### Full Code Solution 2

```
alias useName1 "setinfo name "First_name"; bind "key" useName2"
alias useName2 "setinfo name "Second_name"; bind "key" useName1"
bind "key" useName1
```

Answer (score -2):

Full Code Solution 2 - work fine WITHOUT setinfo

```
alias useName1 "dota_spectator_mode "1"; bind "c" useName2"
alias useName2 "dota_spectator_mode "3"; bind "c" useName1"
bind "c" useName1
```

Comment: The only thing you've really changed is the part which sets the users name, which is specifically what the original question asks for :\